# Knockout.js and jQuery Mobile – Group Array by Day and Have a list-divider for Each Day

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I’m working on a project that is using knockout.js and jQuery Mobile.  I have an observable array of observable properties.  This observable array is getting populated with JSON data via an AJAX call to the server (Web API).

```
// ViewModel
my.vm = function () {
    var
    alarms = ko.observableArray([]),
    loadAlarmsCallback = function (json) {
        $.each(json.Alarms, function (i, p) {
            alarms.push(new my.Alarm()
                .AlarmID(p.AlarmID)
                .StartTime(my.utilities.formatDate(p.StartTime))
                .EndTime(my.utilities.formatDate(p.EndTime))
                .TimeAcknowledged(my.utilities.formatDate(p.TimeAcknowledged))
                .AcknowledgedBy(p.AcknowledgedBy)
                .AlarmType(p.AlarmType)
                .AlarmCategory(p.AlarmCategory)
                .AlarmPriority(p.AlarmPriority)
                .Message(p.Message));
        }),
    loadAlarms = function () {
        my.dataService.getAllAlarms(my.vm.loadAlarmsCallback);
    },
    ...;
    return {
        alarms: alarms,
        loadAlarmsCallback: loadAlarmsCallback,
        loadAlarms: loadAlarms,
        ...
    };
}();

my.vm.loadAlarms();
ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
```

As you can see, each row in the array in the viewmodel has a StartTime, which is actually a date and time that is getting formatted to MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm.

In my view (a jQuery Mobile enabled .cshtml file), I have a foreach binding for the array on ul/li tags.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: alarms" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
    <!-- NEED ONLY ONE list-divider PER DAY -->
    <li data-role="list-divider"><span data-bind="text: StartTime"></span></li>
    <!-- NEED MULTIPLE li TAGS FOR EACH ALARM ON THAT DAY -->
    <li>
        <p><span data-bind="text: AlarmCategory"></span></p>
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I need is only one list-divider row per day to be displayed with all the individual alarm rows on that day to be grouped under that list-divider row.  When the day changes (based on the StartTime value in the viewmodel’s observable array), a new list-divider row is created and displayed with that day’s alarms underneath it.

Anyway, how can I code this scenario?  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is making a computed observable `alertsPerDay` which builds an array where each element corresponds to one day. The element's value is an object containing the date (because you want to show it in the view) and a nested array of alarms which belong to that day. Then in the HTML you can have a nested `foreach` for each day's alarms. It's not trivial to build but it's not too complex either.

Here's a simple example of how to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/KXhem/49/

The main idea is that you can represent your data in the way that's most suitable for your views, and then the KO bindings themselves are trivial.

Comment: That looks great!  And should be very helpful.  I'll try implementing it in my project right away and see how it goes.  Thanks again.